# Email a textbox input using simple php code?

Tags: php, email, input, textbox

The code I am using now is

```
<form name="form" method="post">
Codeword: <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
<?
$a=@$_POST["text_box"];
$myFile = "t.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh,$a);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

I would like to email myself this codeword, when a user submits. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is, what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: You forgot `action=""` in your form.

Comment: Assuming you're running this on a server that can mail, I can't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers  = "From: Siddharth Jain <email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Siddharth Jain <email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: email\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: Siddharth Jain <email>\r\n";
$headers .= "PHP/" . phpversion();

$to = $_REQUEST['email'];

$subject="";

$mailcontent='Codeword: '.$_POST["text_box"];

mail($to, $subject, $mailcontent, $headers);
```

Replace "email" with your email and "Siddharth Jain" with the name you need to display in that email.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic stuff! Use the php [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)function to send an email to yourself.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    mail('yourmail@email.com', 'The codeword', strip_tags($_POST["text_box"]));
}
```

Comment: You might want to do `strip_tags($_POST["text_box"])` for security reasons (to prevent malicious HTML).

Comment: use the mail() function to send mail! that's so crazy it just may work

Comment: Thanks I don't know much PHP that's all :)

Comment: It works, would it be possible to not send the email upon webpage loading though? Only on the instance of the submit button being pressed?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $num))
```

_

```
error: Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\chk\email\emailval.php on line 8
```

Comment: Your answer have formatting problems. Can you please fix it?