# PHP Send a mail to user mail address entered into a text box

Tags: php, forms, email, hyperlink, send

I am trying to make a simple form that sends the user defined/entered email address a link to them.

Visitor > Enter Mail > Hit Send > Receives a mail with a link

But I am battling to make it work.

Comment: for this you can get answer from 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247031/email-a-textbox-input-using-simple-php-code

Comment: share your code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$headers  = "From: Siddharth Jain <email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Siddharth Jain <email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: email\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: Siddharth Jain <email>\r\n";
$headers .= "PHP/" . phpversion();`

$to = $_REQUEST['email'];

$subject="";

$mailcontent='Codeword: '.$_POST["text_box"];

mail($to, $subject, $mailcontent, $headers);

Replace "email" with your email and "Siddharth Jain" with the name you need to display in that email.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Mitali Mehta :)

Got this to work.

```
    <?php
// Contact subject
$subject ="mail subject"; 

// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="no-reply@domain.com"; 

// From 
$header="from: no-reply@domain.com";

// Enter your email address
$to = $_REQUEST['customer_mail'];
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
header("Location:http://www.domain.com/");
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

in case someone else wants it :)
also this sends me a copy of the request too.